# Default security policy for applets

Tags: java, security, applet, policy

Where do I find the policy file that is used for applets?

It is NOT the one in `<jre>/lib/security/java.policy`, because you can instantiate the Calendar.class in an applet, which is not possible with the default java.policy file.

For example, this fails:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
}
```

but in an applet (within its own Security manager) in Firefox the Calendar call is allowed:

```
public void init() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
}
```

I just don't know how to emulate an Applet-like environment in regard to permissions of the security manager.

Comment: I don't get it.  Where & when are you calling that code in the applet?  As part of a `main()` method, it would not be called when deployed as an applet.

Comment: Works for me! (So long as I don't set a security manager before running your main.) Can you give the exception with full stack trace you are [presumably] getting, and platform/version numbers? And probably file a bug.

Comment: (Oh, to sort of answer the question. The Oracle PlugIn sets permissions, including Same Origin Policy, in code.